# Demeaning comments made by a high rep user

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, flagging

I have been made aware of a comment talking about me by a high rep user in this post: [Trouble conveying question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30960/trouble-conveying-question):

[image]

In the linked post, I was referencing a different high rep user. As you can see, another high rep user, Eric Wofsey later commented on the answer to the post.

I think this statement is rude and unprofessional. I think Eric Wofsey has stepped out of bounds with this comment.

If one of my professors said this to me in person after I asked them a question, I would be *shocked* if they responded the way Eric Wofsey did, and I would have no problem reporting their statement to the Dean of the department as harrasment.

Thankfully, not one of my professors would ever do something that unprofessional.

I would like to make it clear that I will not tolerate this harrasment and would like to see action taken by the moderators.

Comment: see the flag ... use it. no need to publicly shame. Your doing the equivalent to what eric did to you.

Comment: @Roddy is right. The equivalent to reporting a prof to the Dean is flagging for moderator attention. What you've done here is the equivalent of hiring a skywriter to publicize your complaint about a prof.

Comment: I'm pretty sure If your professors did that, we wouldn't be having a discussion.

Comment: Call-out culture at its finest. I wish this weren't the norm...

Comment: how is this the product of a generations age with it's complex conjugate ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee The embarrassment is positive definite for everyone unlucky enough to read it.

Comment: Flagging the comment would have done nothing.

Comment: @Ultradark And what do you think that you have achieved acting this way?

Comment: In addition to what Roddy said, I want to honestly add my opinion that I don't think Eric was crossing the line here. He might have been a bit too harsh, perhaps, but can you really say he is wrong? Regardless of the way he said it, I think the point he made was valid and important.

Comment: I don't understand why a high rep users in MSE should be evaluated as if they were a professor in University.

Comment: The OP's answer fills in some gaps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752308/how-to-relearn-undergrad-and-tackle-grad-mathematics-want-to-become-a-better-ma/3248078#3248078

Answer (score 5):

He wasn't being mean. MathOverflow is meant for specialized research level material.   Mathematics is 99+% definitions, and implications.

[Evaluate $ \ln(\zeta(e^s))=0 $ for $s\in\Bbb C.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3497805/evaluate-ln-zetaes-0-for-s-in-bbb-c) suggest you don't know https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm

namely that log is multivalued on the complex plane.

Comment: his answer explains some things: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752308/how-to-relearn-undergrad-and-tackle-grad-mathematics-want-to-become-a-better-ma/3248078#3248078

Comment: I'm like that yo some extent, but I also get the seriousness.